# Kotlin Voice Record Uploading Overwriting on Firebase

Tags: kotlin, firebase-storage

Hello guysi write some code to taking a audio record for saving on firebase. Its work but always saving with same name so its caused the over-writing. How can i fix this ?

```
  mFileName = externalCacheDir!!.absolutePath
    mFileName += "/recorded_audio.3gp"


     private fun startRecording() {
    mRecorder = MediaRecorder()
    mRecorder!!.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
    mRecorder!!.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
    mRecorder!!.setOutputFile(mFileName)
    mRecorder!!.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)

    try {
        mRecorder!!.prepare()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed")
    }

    mRecorder!!.start()
}

private fun stopRecording() {
    mRecorder!!.stop()
    mRecorder!!.release()
    mRecorder = null
    uploadAudio()
}

private fun uploadAudio() {

    val filepath = mStorage!!.child("Audio").child("new_audio.3gp")
    val uri = Uri.fromFile(File(mFileName!!))
    filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener { }

}

companion object {
    private val LOG_TAG = "Record_log"
}
```

Comment: _"How can i fix this?"_ By specifying a different filename for each recording? (e.g. using a counter in your SharedPrecerences)

Comment: Can you give me e simple example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you always use the same file name:

```
mFileName = externalCacheDir!!.absolutePath
mFileName += "/recorded_audio.3gp"
```

If you generate a random UUID (or similar) like:

```
mFileName = externalCacheDir!!.absolutePath
mFileName += "/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".3gp"
```

You'll no longer overwrite files.